# Badrequestkeyerror robobrowser

Tags: python, web-scraping, robobrowser

I am trying to submit a text value into a form to get to another page, but all I am getting is Badrequestkeyerror. Can anyone help me understand what it is and how I can solve for my code? I tried implementing things already available on the [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zy9kV.png)internet but none of them seemed to work.

```
from robobrowser import RoboBrowser

br = RoboBrowser()
br.open("http://stats.espncricinfo.com/ci/engine/stats/index.html")
form = br.get_form()

form['guruInput'] = 'SR Tendulkar'
br.submit_form(form)
src = str(br.parsed())
```